# Add Variable Value Into String With Triple Quotation Marks

Tags: python, html, api

I have a variable defined as follows:

```
item_title="Title"
```

And I want to put this value into the following string:

```
        html_desc="""
<![CDATA[
<head>
<style>
body {
    font-size: 25px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: green;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #FFFFC2;
    padding: 15px;
}

li {
    color: #F7270F;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Auctions for Week of 08-01-2018</h1>
<p>You are bidding on the following item:</p>
<ul><li>"{}".format(item_title)</li></ul>
<p>Condition is pack fresh unless otherwise indicated. Please review the pictures carefully and if you have any questions about something specific, ask.</p>
<p><b>Shipping:</b> Shipping will be calculated based on buyer location. No premiums are charged. Cards are mailed in an 8x5 bubble mailer and shipped First Class mail unless the price exceeds $50, at which point they will be shipped Priority at no additional cost to the buyer. If you win multiple auctions, please wait for an invoice to be sent.</p>
</body>
]]>"""
```

My attempt here is broken. I've also tried using {} and the .format at the end after the final three """ but that isn't working either.

Any assistance?

Comment: Please post your code with the ,format() call at the end, after the three """.  That should work: .format is a method of class str and does not know how the str object was defined.  It mattes not if the literal uses 1 or 3 quotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can not use format because you used these `{}` brackets in style section, but you can do it easily by **Plus Operator** (`+`) like:-

```
html_desc="""
<![CDATA[
<head>
<style>
body {
    font-size: 25px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: green;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #FFFFC2;
    padding: 15px;
}

li {
    color: #F7270F;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Auctions for Week of 08-01-2018</h1>
<p>You are bidding on the following item:</p>
<ul><li>""" + item_title + """</li></ul>
<p>Condition is pack fresh unless otherwise indicated. Please review the pictures 
carefully and if you have any questions about something specific, ask.</p>
<p><b>Shipping:</b> Shipping will be calculated based on buyer location. No premiums are charged. Cards are mailed in an 8x5 bubble mailer and shipped First Class mail unless the price exceeds $50, at which point they will be shipped Priority at no additional cost to the buyer. If you win multiple auctions, please wait for an invoice to be sent.</p>
</body>
]]>"""
```